# Нужна помощь в понимании поведения flex-box элемента в определенных условиях

Tags: css, flexbox

Нужна помощь знающих людей в поведении flex-box элементов в адаптивной верстке.

Что заставляет в **Примере 1** при изменении ширины экрана выпадать элементам из родителя, а в **Примере 2** корректно отрабатывать? В моем понимании работы flex- элементов, они должны нормально сжиматься в обоих ситуациях (В данном случае пока их высота не начнет превышать высоту родителя заданную 200px, сделанную для получения данного расположения блоков в **Примере 1**).

[image: Скрин]

```css
.wrapper{
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px 20px;
}

.items{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 200px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item{
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 0;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 5px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-break: break-word;
  background: #fff;
}
.first .item:first-child{
  flex: 1 1 100%;
}
```

```html
<p>Пример 1</p>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="items first">
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
  </div>
</div>

<p>Пример 2</p>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="items second">
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Для `.item` убери `white-space` и добавь `width: calc(50% - 10px);`

Comment: @ Qwertiy - Круто. Отличное решение. Но вопрос остался почему блоки не жмутся какая сила на них влияет?

Comment: Потому и не в ответах. Видимо, сам флекс так устроен... У меня такое чувство, что в коде какой-то косяк, который должен легко исправляться, но я его найти не могу ((

Comment: @Qwertiy - по сути код взят с https://webref.ru/css/flex-basis

Comment: Ну flex-basis у тебя по вертикальной оси - он работает - первый элемент растянулся на всю высоту.

Comment: @Qwertiy - да flex-basis отрабатывает правильно. Относительно основного вопроса, складывается впечатление, что ширина радителя становится по элементу с flex-basis, а все остальное игнорируется до тех пор пока элемент не упрется в родителя. http://joxi.ru/LmGa94diw9W49A текст переносится только когда достигнуты границы родителя. Но это сугубо мое предположение.

Comment: flex-basis в примере 1 отвечает за высоту, поэтому он не может влиять на ширину. А вот почему блоки имеют одиноковую ширину, не понятно.

Comment: @E_K - Поддерживаю, правильный вопрос.

Comment: Я к пришел к выводу, что копать нужно в сторону работы **flexbox cross size**, какие значения используются для задания ширины и тп. Если явно задать значения `width` для блоков, такой проблемы нет.

Comment: Да грузи ты уже картинки на SO. У меня заблокирован joxi.